# Shouldn't there be "analytically" instead of "analytical" here?

Tags: conjunctions

I read a definition of "clinical" in Merriam Webster dictionaries which was:

> Analytical or coolly dispassionate

I suppose there should be "analytically" instead of "analytical" in the definition because there should be adverb before adjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you interpret the items on either side of the conjunction **or** in that dictionary entry.

If you're thinking of adjectives, one a single word and the other an adjectival phrase, then:

> He is *analytical*. **or**
>   He is *coolly dispassionate*.
>
> → He is (analytical) **or** (coolly dispassionate).

But if you're thinking of two individual adverbs, each modifying *dispassionate*, then:

> He is *analytically* dispassionate.  **or**
>   He is *coolly* dispassionate.
>
> → He is (analytically **or** coolly) dispassionate.

The dictionary entry is interpreting it in the first sense.

Answer (score 0):

This definition lists two adjectives:

1. Analytical
2. Coolly dispassionate

The first adjective is not modified by an adverb, the second is.

Hence, there's no need to change "analytical" to "analytically".